# Controlling returned content

Tags: php

I have the following function in a class:

```
public function getDomains($RESELLER)
{
    $data['object'] = 'domain';
    $data['action'] = 'read';
    $data['territory'] = $RESELLER;
    $data['format'] = 'json';
    if ($response = $this->request($data)) {
        $obj = json_decode($response, true);
        foreach ($obj as $file) {
                return $file['domain'];
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following:

```
$Domains = $api->getDomains($RESELLER);
echo $Domains."<br>";
```

If I change the return to echo in the function, it will print all the domains. But if I leave it as it is, I only get the one value. I tried doing a foreach on the $Domains for the return but I ended up with an error.

My end result is I want to be able to take my returned value and pass it to another function so I can leave this function with just one job without making it into a function doing more then just one job.

Comment: return leaves a function immediately, so your loop only makes it halfway through its first iteration. Gather the content by appending it to an array variable, and return the content of that variable after the loop.

Comment: The foreach loop only ever does the first itteration because the return in that loop returns that first value and breaks out of the loop.

Comment: How do you want to see the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` terminates a function and returns the value. One solution could be to collect all the domains to an array and then return it:

```
public function getDomains($RESELLER)
{
    $data['object'] = 'domain';
    $data['action'] = 'read';
    $data['territory'] = $RESELLER;
    $data['format'] = 'json';
    $retval = array(); # Create the array
    if ($response = $this->request($data)) {
        $obj = json_decode($response, true);
        foreach ($obj as $file) {
            $retval[] = $file['domain']; # Add values to it
        }
    }
    return $retval; # Return it
}
```

Comment: OP prob wants ` $data` part of the return set

Comment: This is not going to work well with a `echo $Domains."<br>";` now is it

Answer (score 1):

Return will return from the function when its hit, hence why your only getting a single row,

Store the result in an array and then return:

```
public function getDomains($RESELLER)
{
        $data['object'] = 'domain';
        $data['action'] = 'read';
        $data['territory'] = $RESELLER;
        $data['format'] = 'json';
        $data['domain'] = array();
        if ($response = $this->request($data)) {
            $obj = json_decode($response, true);
            foreach ($obj as $file) {
                $data['domain'][] = $file['domain'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work well with a `echo $Domains."<br>";` now is it